How to deploy new model version to Vertex endpoint?

I have a model uploaded to Model Registry, which I am successfully deploying to an endpoint with the code below:
from google.cloud import aiplatform

aiplatform.init(project="test-project", location="us-west2")

model = aiplatform.Model.upload(
    display_name="test-model",
    artifact_uri="gs://test-bucket/model",
    serving_container_image_uri="us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/test-project/test-docker-repo/test-inferencer:latest",
    serving_container_environment_variables={
        "HF_TASK": "zero-shot-classification",
        "VERTEX_CPR_WEB_CONCURRENCY": 1,
    },
)

endpoint = model.deploy(
    machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    accelerator_type="NVIDIA_TESLA_T4",
    accelerator_count=1,
    max_replica_count=10,
)

I can update the model version in the registry with the code below:
model_v2 = aiplatform.Model.upload(
    parent_model=model.resource_name,
    display_name="test-model",
    artifact_uri="gs://test-bucket/model_v2",
    serving_container_image_uri="us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/test-project/test-docker-repo/test-inferencer:latest",
    serving_container_environment_variables={
        "HF_TASK": "zero-shot-classification",
        "VERTEX_CPR_WEB_CONCURRENCY": 1,
    },
)

But how do I update the model version in the endpoint? Do I have to undeploy the old model and deploy the new one to the endpoint, or is there a way to make it update automatically?
TIA

Hi @lotif, I am not sure about the automatic process  but you can have a look at this documentation, regarding deploying more than one model to the same endpoint. let me know if this helps you or not.

Thanks for that. I was hoping for something less manual but I guess that would have to do.

Hi @lotif, I have provided the above comment as an answer, if you find it helpful, please do consider upvoting and accepting it as per stackoverflow guidelines helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

As I commented above, you can deploy the updated version of the model as a new one to the same endpoint as it is possible to deploy more than one model to the same endpoint. You can refer to this documentation for more information.

You need to adapt this code to your use case: you deploy a new model to the endpoint and redirect 100% of the traffic to this new model, undeploying the previous version.
endpoints = aiplatform.Endpoint.list(
            filter='display_name="{}"'.format("your-endpoint"),
            order_by='create_time desc',
            project="test-project", location="us-west2",
        )
    
traffic_percentage = 100
machine_type = "n1-standard-16"
sync = True

endpoint = model_uploaded.deploy(
    endpoint=endpoints[-1],
    deployed_model_display_name=DISPLAY_NAME,
    machine_type=machine_type,
    traffic_percentage=traffic_percentage,
    sync=sync,
)
# undeploy models without traffic for this specific endpoint
for model in endpoint.list_models():
    print(model)
    if model.id not in endpoint.traffic_split:
        endpoint.undeploy(deployed_model_id = model.id)


As pointed out by Dhiraj Singh, it has to be done manually. For future reference, the gist below has the script I made to do that.
https://gist.github.com/lotif/41c9c503405620715ecb191a8bc4d19d
